# Difference between "marked bags" and "labeled bags"

Tags: difference, translation

I have a Russian sentence in which lab tubes with different biomaterial should be placed into bags, and these bags should be **[промаркированы](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&langlist=1)** (pro**mark**irovany), that is, there should be some writing on the bags to indicate the contents.

I wonder which would be better:

> Place the tubes with different biomaterials into **marked** blue bags.

> Place the tubes with different biomaterials into **labeled** blue bags.

Are these two completely similar? In my imagination, "marked" is closer to "somebody left some marks on the bag with a marker" and "labeled" is closer to "somebody attached a (sticky) paper label on the bag". Is that so?

The Russian sentence does not indicate the exact way of "marking" the bags, it just says that some indication must appear on them so that the handling persons know what they contain.

Comment: [*Tag 'em and bag 'em*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tag+em+and+bag+em%22), as they say about military casualties and evidence found at crime scenes. But I'd be happy with ***..into tagged blue bags*** in OP's context - regardless of whether there's an actual "tag" attached to each bag (a label on a ***cord / tie***, as opposed to a ***sticky / self-adhesive*** label).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - thank you! I haven't thought about the word "tagged", because indeed it conjured up an image os a tag on a cord

Answer (score 2):

I think you've got it right: my impression is exactly as you described it. "Labeled" is the better choice. "Marked" is too generic.